How to dynamically assign TransactionalManager for multiple datasources in Spring boot
Say, I have configured 5 DataSources in my Spring application.
Each of those connections have also created a matching bean of type TransactionalManager.

When I declare a @Service annotated classes that I want to be used in transactional context, I do:
@Service
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionalManagerA")
public class ServiceA {
}

@Service
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionalManagerA")
public class ServiceB {
}

Problem is that for each service, I have to specify qualifier for the TransactionalManager.
If I don't do, I get exception expected single matching bean but found 5.
Is there a way I can avoid this code duplication?

You could reduce the repeating code by defining a custom annotation per transaction manager:
@Target({ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionalManagerA")
public @interface TransactionalA {
}

Then you would only need to declare your service like:
@Service
@TransactionalA
public class ServiceA {
}

Ideas based on this (not a recommendation, just a side note):

You could, if desired, also move the @Service to that custom annotation and rename it to TxServiceA or something.
Or move those annotations to an interface which your ServiceA class would implement.

